# max and min functions that are similar to colMeans

Tags: r

I am wondering if there are high speed min and max function that works on columns similarly to colMeans?

For 'max', although I can simulate the behavior with 'apply' such as the following:

```
colMax <- function (colData) {
    apply(colData, MARGIN=c(2), max)
}
```

It seems a lot slower than the colMeans in the base package.

Comment: In S-Plus, there are `colMaxs`, `colMedians` and a bunch of other similar functions. Unfortunately R didn't implement all of them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`pmax` is ~ 10x faster than `apply`. Still not as fast as `colMeans` though.

```
data = matrix(rnorm(10^6), 100)
data.df = data.frame(t(data))

system.time(apply(data, MARGIN=c(2), max))
system.time(do.call(pmax, data.df))
system.time(colMeans(data))
```

```
> system.time(apply(data, MARGIN=c(2), max))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.133   0.006   0.139 
> system.time(do.call(pmax, data.df))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.013   0.000   0.013 
> system.time(colMeans(data))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.003   0.000   0.002
```

Comment: Another option for matrix `X` is `sapply(seq_len(ncol(X)), function(x) max(X[, x]))`.

Comment: Sure, but the transposition is not free. I see `system.time(do.call(pmax,data.frame(t(data))))` taking the same time as `apply`.

Answer (score 10):

One can always start with profiling, but your hunch seems correct:

```
R> colMax <- function(X) apply(X, 2, max)
R> library(rbenchmark)
R> Z <- matrix(rnorm(100*100), 100, 100)
R> benchmark(colMeans(Z), colMax(Z))
         test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child 
2   colMax(Z)          100   0.350     87.5      0.12        0          0 
1 colMeans(Z)          100   0.004      1.0      0.00        0          0 
R>
```

In that case you may want to consider writing a simple C/C++ function using [inline](http://cran.r-project.org/package=inline) with the basic C API for R, or our [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) package.  That should get your `colMeans`-alike speed.

*Edit:* Here is a more complete example. `colMeans` still wins, but we're getting closer:

```
R> suppressMessages(library(inline))
R> suppressMessages(library(rbenchmark))
R>
R> colMaxR <- function(X) apply(X, 2, max)
R>
R> colMaxRcpp <- cxxfunction(signature(X_="numeric"), plugin="Rcpp",
+                           body='
+   Rcpp::NumericMatrix X(X_);
+   int n = X.ncol();
+   Rcpp::NumericVector V(n);
+   for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
+      Rcpp::NumericVector W = X.column(i);
+      V[i] = *std::max_element(W.begin(), W.end());  // from the STL
+   }
+   return(V);
+ ')
R>
R>
R> Z <- matrix(rnorm(100*100), 100, 100)
R> benchmark(colMeans(Z), colMaxR(Z), colMaxRcpp(Z), replications=1000, order="relative")
           test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child 
1   colMeans(Z)         1000   0.036  1.00000      0.04        0          0 
3 colMaxRcpp(Z)         1000   0.050  1.38889      0.05        0          0 
2    colMaxR(Z)         1000   1.002 27.83333      1.01        0          0 
R>
```

Comment: PS I take it back.  I've spent a few minutes dinking around with the new `parallel` package and it seems that the overhead is just too large unless you're cleverer than I am ...

Comment: The one issue here is to process NAs. It can be impute by "0" before calculations "colMaxs"

Answer (score 7):

The [matrixStats](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matrixStats/index.html) package has a lot of great functions, including [colMaxs](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/matrixStats/docs/rowRanges).

Answer (score 6):

I am posting an answer only because I don't have enough reputation to comment or vote up/down yet.

The top answer that `pmax` is ~10x times faster than `apply` is not always correct. For example, calculate the max for 10^6 numbers in each column.

```
data <- matrix(rnorm(10^8), 10^6)
data.t <- t(data)
data.df <- data.frame(data)
data.t.df = data.frame(data.t)

system.time(a <- apply(data, MARGIN=c(2), max))
system.time(b <- sapply(data.df, max))
system.time(e <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(data)), function(x) max(data[, x])))
system.time(c <- do.call(pmax, data.t.df))
system.time(d <- colMaxs(data))

> system.time(a <- apply(data, MARGIN=c(2), max))
   user  system elapsed 
      2       0       2 
> system.time(b <- sapply(data.df, max))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.25    0.00    0.25 
> system.time(e <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(data)), function(x) max(data[, x])))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.83    0.00    0.83 
> system.time(c <- do.call(pmax, data.t.df))
   user  system elapsed 
  15.94    0.00   15.96 
> system.time(d <- colMaxs(data))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.21    0.00    0.20
```

Now calculate the max for 100 numbers in each column.

```
system.time(a <- apply(data.t, MARGIN=c(2), max))
system.time(b <- sapply(data.t.df, max))
system.time(e <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(data.t)), function(x) max(data.t[, x])))
system.time(c <- do.call(pmax, data.df))
system.time(d <- colMaxs(data.t))

> system.time(a <- apply(data.t, MARGIN=c(2), max))
   user  system elapsed 
   4.41    0.00    4.42 
> system.time(b <- sapply(data.t.df, max))
   user  system elapsed 
   3.23    0.00    3.23 
> system.time(e <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(data.t)), function(x) max(data.t[, x])))
   user  system elapsed 
   3.57    0.00    3.57 
> system.time(c <- do.call(pmax, data.df))
   user  system elapsed 
   1.56    0.00    1.56 
> system.time(d <- colMaxs(data.t))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.25    0.00    0.25
```

It seems like `pmax` is only comparable or better than `apply` in speed when the number of rows is small (e.g. 100). When the number of rows is large (e.g. 10^6), `pmax` is much slower than `apply`.

In any case, `colMaxs` in the `matrixStats` package is the fastest, and seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Yes, `matrixStats` is at least twice as fast as any other known solution for this, cf. https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/matrixStats/wiki/colRowMins.  That benchmark report also show that although `lapply+pmin` is often faster than `apply+min` it's not always the case.

Answer (score 1):

`pmin` and `pmax` can be used easily to get row mins and maxes, but its a bit awkward for columns.

```
# row maxes
do.call("pmax",mtcars)
 [1] 160.0 160.0 108.0 258.0 360.0 225.0 360.0 146.7 140.8 167.6 167.6 275.8
[13] 275.8 275.8 472.0 460.0 440.0  78.7  75.7  71.1 120.1 318.0 304.0 350.0
[25] 400.0  79.0 120.3 113.0 351.0 175.0 335.0 121.0

# col maxes
do.call("pmax",data.frame(t(mtcars)))
 [1]  33.900   8.000 472.000 335.000   4.930   5.424  22.900   1.000   1.000
[10]   5.000   8.000
```

Another option is `max.col`, which also (confusingly) gives row maxes by default.

```
mmtcars <- as.matrix(mtcars)
mmtcars[max.col(t(mmtcars))+(seq(dim(mmtcars)[2])-1)*dim(mmtcars)[1]]
 [1]  33.900   8.000 472.000 335.000   4.930   5.424  22.900   1.000   1.000
[10]   5.000   8.000
```

Comment: Since `mtcars` is a data.frame, you could use `sapply(mtcars, max)`.