# Column-wise max in R

Tags: r, max, apply

What is the fastest way to obtain a vector consisting of the maximum value from each column of a matrix-like object? Is there a faster alternative to `apply(A, 2, max)` in base R?

`?colSums` says it is "equivalent to use of apply with FUN = sum with appropriate margins, but a lot faster". Unfortunately there seems to be no `colMax`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: matrix or data.frame?

Comment: matrix in my particular case

Comment: have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824912/max-and-min-functions-that-are-similar-to-colmeans

Comment: Thank you! Strange that it didn't come up in my searches.

Comment: The `pmax` solution offered there assumes a data.frame and the time comparison does not account for the conversion from matrix to data.frame. Overall, with the conversion, it is slightly slower... That's why my first question was whether the OP had a matrix or a data.frame. Also, @tennenrishin, what are your matrix dimensions?

Comment: I missed the fact that the conversion was not included. My matrix is about 30x30, but the call is repeated on many matrices, hence the question.

Comment: it takes a fraction of a millisecond for apply to process one matrix. You'd need tens of thousands of matrices to start noticing a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your own c++ function using `Rcpp`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h> 
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector colMaxRcpp(NumericMatrix X) {
    int ncol = X.ncol();
    Rcpp::NumericVector out(ncol);
    for (int col = 0; col < ncol; col++){
        out[col]=Rcpp::max(X(_, col)); 
    } 
    return wrap(out);
}
```

Here some benchmarking:

```
A <- matrix(rnorm(1e6),ncol=10000)
apply.max <- function(A) apply(A, 2, max)
identical(colMaxRcpp(A),apply.max(A))
[1] TRUE

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(colMaxRcpp(A),apply.max(A),times=1)
Unit: milliseconds
          expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 colMaxRcpp(A) 11.57765 11.57765 11.57765 11.57765 11.57765     1
  apply.max(A) 79.66040 79.66040 79.66040 79.66040 79.66040     1
```

**EDIT** add benchmarking for a  matrix 30*30. Rcpp is ate least 12 times faster.

```
A <- matrix(rnorm(30*30),ncol=30)
Unit: microseconds
          expr     min      lq   median      uq      max neval
 colMaxRcpp(A)  13.274  14.033  15.1715  18.584   32.238    10
  apply.max(A) 162.702 166.495 174.0805 189.251 1310.716    10
```