# issue with cxxfunction of package inline

Tags: r, rcpp

I was trying to run the colMaxRCpp function provided by Dirk Eddelbuettel in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824912/max-and-min-functions-that-are-similar-to-colmeans). I'm just repeating the function here so that folks reading this post don't have to click on the link.

```
library(inline)
colMaxRcpp <- cxxfunction(signature(X_="numeric"), plugin="Rcpp", body='
   Rcpp::NumericMatrix X(X_);
   int n = X.ncol();
   Rcpp::NumericVector V(n);
   for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
      Rcpp::NumericVector W = X.column(i);
      V[i] = *std::max_element(W.begin(), W.end());  // from the STL
   }
   return(V);
 ')
```

When I tried to run it, I got the following error:

```
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
file148253859d1.cpp:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
make: *** [file148253859d1.o] Error 1

ERROR(s) during compilation: source code errors or compiler configuration errors!

Program source:
  1: 
  2: // includes from the plugin
  3: 
  4: #include <Rcpp.h>
  5: 
  6: 
  7: #ifndef BEGIN_RCPP
  8: #define BEGIN_RCPP
  9: #endif
 10: 
 11: #ifndef END_RCPP
 12: #define END_RCPP
 13: #endif
 14: 
 15: using namespace Rcpp;
 16: 
 17: 
 18: // user includes
 19: 
 20: 
 21: // declarations
 22: extern "C" {
 23: SEXP file148253859d1( SEXP X_) ;
 24: }
 25: 
 26: // definition
 27: 
 28: SEXP file148253859d1( SEXP X_ ){
 29: BEGIN_RCPP
 30: 
 31:   Rcpp::NumericMatrix X(X_);
 32:   int n = X.ncol();
 33:   Rcpp::NumericVector V(n);
 34:   for (int i=0;i<n; i++) {
 35:     Rcpp::NumericVector W=X.column(i);
 36:     V[i] = *std::max_element(W.begin(),W.end());
 37:   }
 38:   return(V);
 39: 
 40: END_RCPP
 41: }
 42: 
 43: 
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
file148253859d1.cpp:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
make: *** [file148253859d1.o] Error 1
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/bin/x64/R CMD SHLIB file148253859d1.cpp 2>
file148253859d1.cpp.err.txt' had status 1
```

I can't understand the error message above. What can I do to fix this error? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
This is the error if I try `evalCpp("2+2")`

```
g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"C:/Users/Pradipto/Documents/R/win-    library/3.0/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/Pradipto/Documents/R/win-library/3.0/Rcpp/include"         
-I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c     
file1bb87b48650d.cpp -o file1bb87b48650d.o file1bb87b48650d.cpp:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-    bit mode not compiled in make: *** [file1bb87b48650d.o] Error 1 
Error in sourceCpp(code = code, env = env, rebuild = rebuild, showOutput = showOutput,  : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an issue with the code.  Using Rcpp-as-released:

```
R> source("/tmp/uday.R")     ## with your example in this file
R> colMaxRcpp(matrix(1:9,3))
[1] 3 6 9
R>
```

Try something simpler such as

```
R> evalCpp("2 + 2")          ## eval expression via C++ program
[1] 4
R> evalCpp("M_PI")           ## pi as constant in math.h
[1] 3.14159
R>
```

to see that your compiler is fine.

Comment: perhaps the issue is with the "sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in make" - which seems to be the common error between the two processed.

Comment: You need to revisit the installation of Rtools, setting of `$PATH` etc pp.

Comment: I think there was a similar problem posted earlier where a non-Rtools version of make was earlier in the path, and hence being called and failing. Make sure your `Rtools` installation is at the beginning of your path.

Comment: Thanks, `evalCpp("2+2")` works now. The problem was a conflict with a g++ supplied with a Haskell distribution