# cxxfunction does not work Rcpp; inline packages

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Here is the issue, I have `Rcpp` & `inline` installed. After `cppFunction` which worked fine, I tried `cxxfunction` which did not work. Any helps ?

An example taken from this link (see: http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/papers/RcppArmadillo.pdf)

```
g <- cxxfunction(signature(vs="numeric"),
                 plugin="RcppArmadillo",   
                 body='    
 arma::vec v = Rcpp::as<arma::vec>(vs);    
 arma::mat op = v * v.t();    
 double ip = arma::as_scalar(v.t() * v);    
 return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("outer")=op,    
 Rcpp::Named("inner")=ip);',    
 verbose=TRUE
)
```

I'm on windows 7 64bits; the path for R is `"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2"`; Rtools: `"C:\Rtools"` (3.1 version)

I saw this post: [Message error 'C:/Program' not found with Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944594/message-error-c-program-not-found-with-rcpp) but I'm still confused. I tried to set `verbose=TRUE`:

```
Compilation argument:  \
C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/bin/x64/R CMD SHLIB file6b05c233a.cpp 
  file6b05c233a.cpp.err.txt  g++ -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/include"\
  -DNDEBUG \
  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/RcppArmadillo/include" \
  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/Rcpp/include" \
  -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"  \
  -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c file6b05c233a.cpp -o file6b05c233a.o 
C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-30~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf:181: recipe for \
    target 'file6b05c233a.o' failed
file6b05c233a.cpp:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
```

Comment: Do not install in a `$PATH` with spaces.

Comment: The error message is confused about the 64-bit mode.  Do you by chance have other gcc versions installed and the `$PATH` not sorted right?

Comment: I have other gcc versions installed ON "C:\MinGW\" and Geany. Should I remove them? If reinstall in a path without space, I may lost all my installed packages?

Comment: As the installation instructions for R and Rtools clearly state, you MUST add its components to the very beginning of `$PATH`.  Here, you seem to be calling the wrong g++.

Comment: Turns out I answered this once before -- same error message: Possible duplicate of [issue with cxxfunction of package inline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754828/issue-with-cxxfunction-of-package-inline)

Comment: OK, it works now, I successfully reinstalled R, Rtools in a $PATH without space. There was something I checked during installation of Rtools (SytemRoot...) something like that. However, after calling each c++ function, a long message called "Compilation argument" appears : I'm wonder how to disable it