# Big tasks In R, how to avoid for loops to run faster

Tags: r, for-loop, runtime, apply

My code is running but very very slowly. So this is a big problem and it has to run quicker. So here is the task:
I have a dataset with telecommunication records and i want to apply multiple functions on all records to each customer and put the results in a another data frame.

So `df1` is  the data frame where each row has a unique customer id and columns with some profil infomations. `df2` is a very big data frame with about 800 000 telecommunications records identifyed over the customer ids. Now i want to compute e.g. the average data usage for each customer in `df2` and save the result in `df1`.

`df1` looks like

```
df1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, sep=",",
       text="CUSTOMER_ID,Age,ContractType, Gender
       ID1,45,Postpaid,m
       ID2,50,Postpaid,f
       ID3,35,Postpaid,f
       ID4,44,Postpaid,m
       ID5,32,Postpaid,m
       ID6,48,Postpaid,f
       ID7,50,Postpaid,m
       ID8,51,Postpaid,f")
```

`df2` looks like

```
 df2 <- read.table(header = TRUE, sep=",",
   text="CUSTOMER_ID,EVENT,VOLUME, DURATION, MONTH
   ID1,100,500,200,201505
   ID1,50,400,150,201506
   ID1,80,600,50,201507
   ID2,40,800,45,201505
   ID2,25,650,120,201506
   ID2,65,380,250,201507
   ID3,30,950,110,201505
   ID3,25,630,85,201506
   ID3,15,780,60,201507")
```

## My codes is like

```
USAGE <-  c("EVENT", "VOLUME", "DURATION") #column names of df2
```

list of functions i want to apply on `df2`

```
 StatFunctions <- list(  
      max = function(x) max(x), 
      mean = function(x) mean(x), 
      sum = function(x) sum(x)
      )
```

In my original data set the Customer IDs are more complex so i choose this pattern search for the cutsomer ids. This is only a cut out of my code. But with the rest it is the same problem with the for loops.

```
func.num <- function(prefix, target.df, n) {
    active.df <- get(target.df)
    return(StatFunctions[[n]](active.df[grep(pattern = prefix, 
    x = active.df$CUSTOMER_ID), USAGE[m]]))
  }


 for (x in df1$CUSTOMER_ID) {    
      for (m in 1:length(USAGE)) {    
        for (n in 1:length(StatFunctions)) {        
          df1[df1$CUSTOMER_ID == x, paste(names(StatFunctions[n]), 
          USAGE[m], sep = "_")] <- func.num(prefix = x, target.df = "df2",n)      
        }
    }
  }
```

I know the code is very complicated and should be simplified.

And i want a data frame like this

```
Customer_ID Age contractType Gender max_EVENT mean_EVENT sum_EVENT ... sum_DURATION
ID1         45     Postpaid      m     100       76        230     ...     400
```

### So how can i avoid the for loops to run faster?

Comment: To get you started: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/108034/11849.

Comment: You may be interested in Code Review, another Stack Exchange site for reviewing code which is already working

Comment: apply and its derivatives(mapply, sapply, tapply,...) may be helpful. Try with these functions and compare the execution durations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `dplyr` package to summarize `df2` by customer ID, then merge with `df1`.

```
df1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, sep=",",
                  text="CUSTOMER_ID,Age,ContractType, Gender
       ID1,45,Postpaid,m
       ID2,50,Postpaid,f
       ID3,35,Postpaid,f
       ID4,44,Postpaid,m
       ID5,32,Postpaid,m
       ID6,48,Postpaid,f
       ID7,50,Postpaid,m
       ID8,51,Postpaid,f")


df2 <- read.table(header = TRUE, sep=",",
                  text="CUSTOMER_ID,EVENT,VOLUME, DURATION, MONTH
   ID1,100,500,200,201505
   ID1,50,400,150,201506
   ID1,80,600,50,201507
   ID2,40,800,45,201505
   ID2,25,650,120,201506
   ID2,65,380,250,201507
   ID3,30,950,110,201505
   ID3,25,630,85,201506
   ID3,15,780,60,201507")

df1$CUSTOMER_ID <- gsub(" ", "", df1$CUSTOMER_ID)
df2$CUSTOMER_ID <- gsub(" ", "", df2$CUSTOMER_ID)

library(dplyr)
USAGE <- c("EVENT", "VOLUME", "DURATION")
FUNC  <- c("max", "mean", "sum")
dots <- lapply(USAGE, function(u) sprintf("%s(%s)", FUNC, u)) %>% unlist()
dots <- setNames(dots, sub("\\)", "", sub("\\(", "_", dots)))
sum_df <- df2 %>% group_by(CUSTOMER_ID) %>%
  summarize_(.dots = dots) %>% 
  ungroup()

df1$CUSTOMER_ID <- as.character(df1$CUSTOMER_ID)
sum_df$CUSTOMER_ID <- as.character(sum_df$CUSTOMER_ID)
df1 <- left_join(df1, sum_df)
```

Comment: A big thank you. This is so much faster and saves a lot of time!!

Answer (score 0):

First we fetch the columns that are to be operated on and the ID's

```
mycols <- c("EVENT","VOLUME","DURATION")
id <- levels(df2$CUSTOMER_ID)
```

We are going to do this by using the (much faster) apply functions, that will allow us to do the operations parallel on each column, instead of one by one. Create a function that takes such operation on each of the columns. This we will apply over each ID.

For taking mean and summing, we may use the ([very fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824912/max-and-min-functions-that-are-similar-to-colmeans)) `colMeans` and `colSums`.

```
applyfun <- function(i,FUN){
    FUN(df2[df2$CUSTOMER_ID == i,mycols])
}
```

For maximum, we create a similar function

```
colMax <- function (colData) {
    apply(colData, MARGIN=c(2), max)
}
```

Apply the three functions

```
outmean <- sapply(id,applyfun,colMeans)
outsum <- sapply(id,applyfun,colSums)
outmax <- sapply(id,applyfun,colMax)

out <- data.frame(CUSTOMER_ID = rownames(t(outmean)), 
                  mean = t(outmean),
                  sum = t(outsum),
                  max = t(outmax))
```

Merge the data onto `df1`

```
merge(df1,out,key = "CUSTOMER_ID",all.x = TRUE)
```

which gives the output:

> ```
>   CUSTOMER_ID Age ContractType Gender mean.EVENT ... max.DURATION
> 1         ID1  45     Postpaid      m   76.66667 ...          200
> 2         ID2  50     Postpaid      f   43.33333 ...          250
> 3         ID3  35     Postpaid      f   23.33333 ...          110
> 4         ID4  44     Postpaid      m         NA ...           NA
> ```

---

I had some whitespace problems with the `CUSTOMER_ID` from your examples of `df1` and `df2` and suppose you do not. To fix this I used

```
df1$CUSTOMER_ID <- as.factor(trimws(df1$CUSTOMER_ID))
df2$CUSTOMER_ID <- as.factor(trimws(df2$CUSTOMER_ID))
```